# incorrect output in MIPs program

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I'm implementing the following code from c to mips assembly

```
/*
  Given an array arr terminated by entry -1, transform the array by adding
  to each entry the sum of the remainder of the array after that entry.
  That is, if initially arr == [a_0, a_1, ..., a_n, -1], then finally
  arr == [b_0, b_1, ..., b_n, -1], where b_j = sum(a_i for i in j..n-1).
 */

uint32_t reverse_prefix_sum(uint32_t *arr) {
  uint32_t r;

  if(*arr == -1) return 0;
  r = reverse_prefix_sum(arr+1) + (uint32_t)*arr;
  *arr = r;        /* may discard MSB */
  return(r);
}
```

My current program is the following:

```
reverse_prefix_sum: # Let the address of array arr be in $a0
    # adjust the stack pointer to save $a0 and $ra
    addi $sp,$sp,-8
    sw $a0,0($sp)
    sw $ra,4($sp)
    # Load *arr
    lw $t0,0($a0)
    beq $t0,-1,exit1 # r is in $v0

    # *arr = *arr + 1
    addu $a0,$a0,4 # recursive call
    jal reverse_prefix_sum
    addu $v0,$v0,$t0
    # restore $a0
    lw $a0,0($sp)
    #restore $ra
    lw $ra,4($sp)
    add $sp,$sp,8
    sw $v0,0($a0)
    jr $ra
exit1:
    # restore $a0
    lw $a0,0($sp)
    #restore $ra
    lw $ra,4($sp)
    addi $sp,$sp,8
    # return 0
    li $v0,0
    jr $ra
```

With input 1 2 3 4 -1, I'm getting output -4 -3 -2. 
I'm wondering where this could be improved to fix the output being incorrect.

Comment: Why don't you call it postfix-sum? Also, you're not keeping track of which registers are caller-saved and which are callee-saved, so you fail to reload clobbered values.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that t0 isn’t preserved across the function call. Reload it from 0(a0) after restoring a0 after the function returns.